# Smart Table filter is resetting when I select on a filtered row

Tags: javascript, angularjs, smart-table

I'm new to Angular.js as well as Smart Table.  I have a table functioning how I wish, except for one small problem I can not figure out.

I have a selectDistinct dropdown that filters the displayedCollection, and that works.

I also have a checkbox per row that when you click, selects the row (or rows).  This also works.

The problem I am having is when I try to do both together.  If I select one of my dropdown filters, it filters the rows as expected. Then I click on one of the checkboxes to select a row, and as soon as I do that the table/filters reset and it shows all my records again.  I would like for the select to function without resetting the table and keeping the filters I have selected in place.

Here is the relevant code:

**HTML**

```
<table st-set-filter="customFilter" st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="rowCollection">
<thead>
    <tr class="table-header">
        <th class="check"></th>
        <th class="patient-name" st-sort="patientName">Patient Name</th>

        <th class="patient-number" st-sort="patientNumber" st-skip-natural="true">Patient #</th>
        <th class="prescription-type" st-sort="approvalType">Perscription Type</th>
        <th class="date-of-birth" st-sort="dateRequested">Date Requested</th>
        <th class="provider" st-sort="provider">Provider</th>
        <th class="location" st-sort="location">Location</th>
        <th class="status" st-sort="status">Status</th>

    </tr>
    <tr class="table-search">
        <th class="check">
           <st-select-all all="displayedCollection"></st-select-all>
        </th>
        <th class="patient-name">
            <input class="patient-name" st-search="patientName" type="search" />
        </th>
        <th class="patient-number">
            <input class="patient-number" st-search="patientNumber" type="search" />
        </th>
        <th class="prescription-type">
            <st-select-distinct collection="rowCollection" predicate="approvalType"></st-select-distinct>
        </th>
        <th class="date-of-birth">
            <input class="date-of-birth" st-search="dateRequested" type="search" />
        </th>
        <th class="provider">
            <st-select-distinct collection="rowCollection" predicate="provider"></st-select-distinct>
        </th>
        <th class="location"></th>
        <th class="status">
            <st-select-distinct collection="rowCollection" predicate="status"></st-select-distinct>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in displayedCollection track by $index" index="{{$index}}" class="patient-profile" >
        <td class="check" st-select="row">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="row.isSelected" id="checkbox{{$index}}">
            <label class="checkbox-sm" for="checkbox{{$index}}"></label>
        </td>
        <td class="patient-name">{{row.patientName}}</td>
        <td class="patient-number">{{row.patientNumber}}</td>
        <td class="prescription-type">{{row.approvalType}}</td>
        <td class="date-of-birth">{{row.dateRequested | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</td>
        <td class="provider">{{row.provider}}</td>
        <td class="location">{{row.location}}</td>
        <td class="status">{{row.status}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**JS**

```
    import angular from 'angular';
import ngRoute from 'angular-route';

import WidgetsController from './widgets.controller.js';

export default angular.module('pages.widgets', [ngRoute])
    .config(config)
    .controller('WidgetsController', WidgetsController)
    .directive('stSelect', [stSelect])
    .directive('stSelectAll', [stSelectAll])
    .directive('stSelectDistinct', [stSelectDistinct])
    .filter('customFilter', ['$filter', customFilter])
    .name;

function config($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/widgets', {
        template: require('./widgets.html'),
        css: require('./widgets.scss'),
        controller: 'WidgetsController'
    });
}

config.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

function stSelect() {
    return {
        require: '^stTable',
        scope: {
            row: '=stSelect'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {

            element.bind('change', function (evt) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    ctrl.select(scope.row, 'multiple');
                });
            });

            scope.$watch('row.isSelected', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue === true) {
                    element.parent().addClass('st-selected');
                } else {
                    element.parent().removeClass('st-selected');
                }
            });
        }
    };
}

function stSelectAll() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="isAllSelected" id="checkAll"><label class="checkbox-sm" for="checkAll"></label>',
        scope: {
            all: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.isAllSelected = false;
            scope.$watch('isAllSelected', function () {
                scope.all.forEach(function (val) {
                    val.isSelected = scope.isAllSelected;
                });
            });
        }
    };
}

function stSelectDistinct() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^stTable',
        scope: {
            collection: '=',
            predicate: '@',
            predicateExpression: '='
        },
        template: '<select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-change="optionChanged(selectedOption)" ng-options="opt for opt in distinctItems"></select>',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, table) {
            var getPredicate = function () {
                var predicate = scope.predicate;
                if (!predicate && scope.predicateExpression) {
                    predicate = scope.predicateExpression;
                }
                return predicate;
            };

            scope.$watch('collection', function (newValue) {
                var predicate = getPredicate();
                if (newValue) {
                    var temp = [];
                    scope.distinctItems = ['All'];
                    angular.forEach(scope.collection, function (item) {
                        var value = item[predicate];

                        if (value && value.trim().length > 0 && temp.indexOf(value) === -1) {
                            temp.push(value);
                        }
                    });
                    temp.sort();

                    scope.distinctItems = scope.distinctItems.concat(temp);
                    scope.selectedOption = scope.distinctItems[0];
                    scope.optionChanged(scope.selectedOption);
                }
            }, true);

            scope.optionChanged = function (selectedOption) {
                var predicate = getPredicate();

                var query = {};

                query.distinct = selectedOption;

                if (query.distinct === 'All') {
                    query.distinct = '';
                }
                table.search(query, predicate);
            };
        }
    };
}

function customFilter($filter) {
    var filterFilter = $filter('filter');
    var standardComparator = function standardComparator(obj, text) {
        text = ('' + text).toLowerCase();
        return ('' + obj).toLowerCase().indexOf(text) > -1;
    };

    return function customFilter(array, expression) {
        function customComparator(actual, expected) {

            var isBeforeActivated = expected.before;
            var isAfterActivated = expected.after;
            var isLower = expected.lower;
            var isHigher = expected.higher;
            var higherLimit;
            var lowerLimit;
            var itemDate;
            var queryDate;

            if (angular.isObject(expected)) {
                //exact match
                if (expected.distinct) {
                    if (!actual || actual.toLowerCase() !== expected.distinct.toLowerCase()) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    return true;
                }

                //matchAny
                if (expected.matchAny) {
                    if (expected.matchAny.all) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    if (!actual) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    for (var i = 0; i < expected.matchAny.items.length; i++) {
                        if (actual.toLowerCase() === expected.matchAny.items[i].toLowerCase()) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }

                    return false;
                }

                //date range
                if (expected.before || expected.after) {
                    try {
                        if (isBeforeActivated) {
                            higherLimit = expected.before;

                            itemDate = new Date(actual);
                            queryDate = new Date(higherLimit);

                            if (itemDate > queryDate) {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }

                        if (isAfterActivated) {
                            lowerLimit = expected.after;


                            itemDate = new Date(actual);
                            queryDate = new Date(lowerLimit);

                            if (itemDate < queryDate) {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }

                        return true;
                    } catch (e) {
                        return false;
                    }

                } else if (isLower || isHigher) {
                    //number range
                    if (isLower) {
                        higherLimit = expected.lower;

                        if (actual > higherLimit) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                    if (isHigher) {
                        lowerLimit = expected.higher;
                        if (actual < lowerLimit) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                    return true;
                }
                //etc

                return true;

            }
            return standardComparator(actual, expected);
        }

        var output = filterFilter(array, expression, customComparator);

        return output;
    };
}
```

Comment: I found a way to fix my problem.  I wrapped the scope.$watch('collection', in a function.

Comment: Hi, @Tim how exactly did you fix your problem? I think i have same problem. Thank you